# Google Analytics: Is there any way to create the Cohort Analysis report using the Analytics API?

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-api

Can't find the cohort dimension or the user acquisition date in the Dimensions and Metrics explorer to feed the data into the Google Script .gs (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to use the [`dateOfSession<>` segment notation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#dateOfSession-example):

```
segment=users::sequence::^ga:sessionCount==1;dateOfSession<>2014-05-20_2014-05-30;->>ga:sessionDurationBucket>600
```

The above segment will give you users who have had their first session between May 20, 2014 and May 30, 2014 and have spent > 600 seconds on the site.

**Updated April, 2016**

As of April 2016, with the release of [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) it is now possible to create [cohort](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#cohorts) reports by directly querying the API:

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
"reportRequests": [
        {
        "viewId": "XXXX",
        "dimensions": [
            {"name": "ga:cohort" },
            {"name": "ga:cohortNthWeek" }],
        "metrics": [
            {"expression": "ga:cohortActiveUsers"}
        ],
        "cohortGroup": {
            "cohorts": [{
                "name": "cohort 1",
                "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
                "dateRange": {
                    "startDate": "2015-08-01",
                    "endDate": "2015-09-01"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "cohort 2",
                "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
                "dateRange": {
                    "startDate": "2015-07-01",
                    "end_date": "2015-08-01"
                }
            }],
        }
    }]
  }
```

The documentation contains [samples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#cohorts) in various languages.

It is important to note lifetime value queries (`"lifetimeValue": True` and all `ga:acquisition...` dimensions), as noted in the [Analytics Help Center](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6182550), can only be queried for [App Views](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649553#WebVersusAppViews)

Comment: Great answer - But is it possible to use this with the add on for google spreadsheets?

Comment: The spreadsheet add-on uses the Core Reporting API V3, which means you would need to use the `dateOfSession<>` segment notation I described in my original answer.